# How do I stop jQuery ui draggable if current move is over picture height size?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/7aVXc/

Let' say current image height is `400px`.

How do I stop the image when the **white background** is appear on top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. add a `drag`-handler which returns `true` or `false` relative to the vertical position:

```
$("#image").draggable({
    ...
    drag:function(event,ui) {
        return (ui.offset.top > -235 && ui.offset.top < 15);
    }
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7aVXc/4/).